# Remove entry from double nester array using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, pull

I'm trying to remove an entry from an array which nested in another array as you can see below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("548f5ca9fa9dc1000016a725"),
    "entries" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("548f5cc8fa9dc1000016a726"),
            "content" : [ 
                {
                    "order" : ObjectId("5489fa9127f1310000bea2ed"),
                    "order_id" : "305429245",
                    "item_id" : "305429245-1"
                }, 
                {
                    "order" : ObjectId("5489fa9127f1310000bea2ce"),
                    "order_id" : "330052901",
                    "item_id" : "330052901-1"

                }
            ],
            "stop_number" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "stop_number" : 2,
            "expected_arrival" : ISODate("2014-12-15T17:11:11.000Z"),
            "expected_departure" : ISODate("2014-12-15T19:03:17.000Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("548fb2826e52c20000bd2299"),
            "content" : []
        }
    ]
}
```

And i'm trying to remove the entry that have '305429245-1', so i used:

```
Q.npost(Manifests, 'findOneAndUpdate', [
        { '_id': id },
        {
            '$pull': {
                'entries.content': { item_id: line_item_id }
            }
        }
    ])
```

where 'id' is the ObjectID (548f5ca9fa9dc1000016a725) and line_item_id = 305429245-1, however, this doesn't work. Can anyone let me know what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use find and Update functions separately instead of findOneAndUpdate

```
Model.find({'_id: id'},function(err,callback){...})
{
//handle callback
}
Model.update({'_id: id'}, {$pull: {'entries.content': item_id: line_item_id}}, function(err,callback){..} )
{
 //do some logic or handle callback
}
```

here **Model** which i mentioned,should be the model you are using.